# intelliJ 13 not recognizing external configuration in navigation bar

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to set up a grails application and I've noticed that intellij doesn't recognize an external configuration file that i Have set up. When looking at another application, that I did not set up, an external configuration will display when listing `project` or `project files` in intelliJ's navigation panel on the left side. I believe I have my configuration file setup in the correct location with the correct naming convention. Grails looks for configuration files in the following locations

```
grails.config.locations = [
    "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
    "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
    "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
    "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy",
    "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}/${appName}-config.properties",
    "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}/${appName}-config.groovy"
    ]
```

I looked at the `application.properties` file and checked the `app.name` variable. It had a value of (as an example) `website`. So I set up my configuration file as such.

`<root>\Users\<username>\website\website-config.groovy`

when I open the project in intelliJ and ran the application (for good measure), i do not see the external configuration file listed in the navigation bar like my other project did. Do I need to enter that manually?